# How to overwrite delegated parameters?

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates

How to overwrite delegated parameters

I do have a service with a method like the below:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IntegracaoParoquia> GetMyStuffFromRepo(MainForm form, Decimal myId)
    {
        IEnumerable<MyStuffClass> stuffCollection = null;

        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            try
            {
                unitOfWork.OpenConnection();
                stuffCollection = GetRepo().GetStuff(myId, unitOfWork.GetConnection(), unitOfWork.GetTransaction());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                unitOfWork.Rollback();
                LogError(form, ex);
            }
        }

        return stuffCollection;
    }
```

but since a can end with dozen call like this I want to wrap them in a generic call like the below:

```
    private static R CallMyRepoMethod<P, R>(MainForm form, P param, Func<P, IDbConnection, IDbTransaction, R> method)
    {
        R result = default(R);

        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            try
            {
                unitOfWork.OpenConnection();
                result = method(param, unitOfWork.GetConnection(), unitOfWork.GetTransaction());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                unitOfWork.Rollback();
                LogError(form, ex);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IntegracaoParoquia> GetMyStuffFromRepo(MainForm form, Decimal myId)
    {
        return CallMyRepoMethod<Decimal, IEnumerable<MyStuffClass>>(form, myId, (x,y,z)=>GetRepo().GetStuff(myId, null, null) );
    }
```

The problem is: I want to keep the `using` inside my delegate (and the provided connection and transaction) but due to the repository method signature. When `(x,y,z)=>GetRepo().GetStuff(myId, null, null)` is called it passes the null values instead of using the correct values from the delegate.
That's reasonable if you consider the `using` is not in the scope outside the delegate.

There's any way to get around it or do I need to rewrite it using `invoke`?

Comment: The word "overwrite" is throwing me off. What does that mean? Also you refer to `GetStuff` but I don't see that method.

Comment: @ScottHannen By "overwrite" I mean I want the parameters of **GetStuff** to be assigned *inside* the delegate. If I run the above example I got null, because its the value I passing when I *call* the delegate. **GetStuff** is just a method to fetch data from the database. I know the question can sound a bit confusing. I know there's a question of scope but I hope someone can give me a tip here on how get it done

Comment: I think I understand. The challenge is that in this case it's not quite clear enough what this code is doing (especially the missing `GetStuff` method) to build an example out of it. If it could be broken down into something smaller that includes the relevant parts and nothing else that would be better. Sometimes that's not necessary but in this case it's harder to visualize (for me, anyway.)

Comment: @ScottHannen Next time I got 30 min I'll try to improve it. For now consider GetStuff is just fetching a collection, like a GetOrdersByCustomerId